# Bucket Sort Asymptotic Running Time with Different Probability Distribution

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, bucket-sort

Consider a bucket-sort algorithm that uses N buckets to sort N elements and we use insertion sort to sort elements in each bucket.

The probability distribution, hypothetically, has been incorrectly analyzed and the effect is that each element has a 10% chance of being placed in bucket 0. The probability of being placed in any other bucket is uniform.

What is the average asymptotic running time for this algorithm?

My professor detailed a solution but I'm confused in a variety of places. Here is the solution:

"As N increases, we can expect N/10 elements in the first slot. In fact the probability of being N/20 and N/5 is essentially 1.

The average # of comparisons for insertion sort of a list of size k is Θ(k^2). That is, there exist constants C1 and C2 such that:

C1k^2 <= #comparisons <= C2k^2

The # of comparisons for the first slot, T0(N) will fall in the range:

C1(N/20)^2 <= T0(N) <= C2(N/5)^2

For the total # of comparisons we have:

T(N) >= T0(N) >= (C1/400)N^2 = Ω(N^2)

Expect the remaining buckets to have 1-2 elements, so the # of comparisons outisde bucket 0 are negligible. Worst case we have:

T(N) <= C2N^2 = O(N^2)

Since T(N) = O(N^2) & T(N) = Ω(N^2), we conclude that T(N) = Θ(N^2)."

1. So why do we use N/20 and N/5?
2. How do we get from here:

"C1(N/20)^2 <= T0(N) <= C2(N/5)^2"

to here:

"T(N) >= T0(N) >= (C1/400)N^2 = Ω(N^2)"

3. Why are the other buckets negligible?

Comment: #1. As illustrative examples - there's nothing magic about those numbers.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth so could they be any numbers?